# CASE with Join | Query Optimization

Tags: sql, eclipse, birt

I need some help Optmizing this query,

It's running on preview mode but when I import the report, the report gets failing

```
select su4.USER_VALUE as CODICE_SKOFF,
      CASE WHEN (su1r.USER_ID = 'A' AND su4.USER_VALUE = '9') THEN 'TestA'
           WHEN (su1r.USER_ID = 'B' AND su4.USER_VALUE = '10') THEN 'TestB'
           WHEN (su1r.USER_ID = 'C' AND su4.USER_VALUE = '11') THEN 'TestC'
           WHEN (su1r.USER_ID = 'D' AND su4.USER_VALUE = '12') THEN 'TestD' 
           ELSE 'None'
      END
```

I think it's because of the `CASE`, it turns the report slow and gets a failing message

after `FROM` I have several `left outer join`

thanks in advance

Comment: What does the meaning of "gets failing"? Syntax error? Error result sets? Or something else, you should provide more info about your post, like your complete sql or full exception stack trace.

Comment: ... and you didn't mention the DB you're using.